# getUserMedia and MediaRecorder - 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

Tags: javascript, html, macos, webrtc, chromium

I have a HTML5 media recorder allowing users to record themselves live inside a web application, playback, and upload the recording.

It uses standard code with `getUserMedia` for getting a handle on the webcam and microphone, `<video>` to playback the webcam, and `MediaRecorder` to record the stream from `getUserMedia`.

So, to the problem...

On some Macbook Air devices, Google Chrome throws error 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable) when trying to playback the recorded stream in the `<video>` element. The issue seems so far to only occur on OSX with Chrome, but it's not occurring on all devices of that combination.

There's a Chromium bug open that references this issue but it is marked as 'Fixed'. 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615940
I'm not convinced however that the full problem is resolved based on the ticket commentary. I recent commenter mentioned this affects Facebook Messenger too!

Have you seen this issue before, and do you know of a workaround for *OSX with Chrome* users that doesn't involve *use Windows* or *use Firefox*?

Comment: I also face this error from time to time, but it's always because of an error in my scripts. Could you share your code as an [MCVE] please ?  (Note : most often it's because my stream is closed when recording)

Comment: @Paul: Chrome just released version 63. Can you verify that things are working better now?

Answer (score 1):

I dug in this a little bit and found that the developers of Chromium are aware of the issue and they confirmed that it's mostly affecting Mac OS users. Seems like there is no workaround for it at the moment.

The good news is that they are shipping an update with Chrome 63, which is coming in December 2017, that should fix it.

[MediaRecorder Gets into Bad State and Raises Empty Data Events](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=654910)

[WebRTC Update 2017](https://youtu.be/PEXnbTyygi4?t=10m33s)