# Simple audio recorder in HTML5: Requested Range Not Satisfiable error

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mediarecorder

I am trying to create a really simple voice recorder page in HTML5 - all it needs to do is record a short snippet of audio from the device microphone and then allow the user to play it back (no persistent storage required).

I started with the sample code in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination), then replaced the oscillator with the stream from a call to getUserMedia. The result worked in Android/Chrome, but in Chrome on my Mac I get the following error:

GET blob:https://sashaforce.github.io/10801957-0b71-4bcd-9ad6-9b33db4a48d7 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable)

A friend tried it on their iPhone and also found that it didn't work, although I wasn't able to get more details than that.

A commenter in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922424/getusermedia-and-mediarecorder-416-requested-range-not-satisfiable) mentions having a stream closed when recording - not sure how that could happen here but did wonder if the blob was going out of scope so first declared it outside of the success handler, then tried saving to sessionStorage but got a different error. Any ideas? The code is below:

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Voice Record Demo</h1>

<p>Record a short voice memo and play it back.</p>

<p>
  <button>Start recording</button>
</p>

<p>
  <audio controls></audio>
</p>

<script>

  var blob;

  var handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    console.log("getUserMedia succeeded");

    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    var clicked = false;
    var chunks = [];

    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);


    button.addEventListener("click", function(element) {
      if (!clicked) {
        mediaRecorder.start();
        element.target.innerHTML = "Stop recording";
        clicked = true;
      } else {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        element.target.disabled = true;
      }
    });

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(evt) {
      // push each chunk (blobs) in an array
      console.log("pushing blob");
      chunks.push(evt.data);
    };

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(evt) {
      // Make blob out of our blobs, and open it.
      console.log("mediaRecorder.onstop");
      blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
      console.log("starting set audio source");
      document.querySelector("audio").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      console.log("finished set audio source");
    };
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
       .then(handleSuccess);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error. In fact, the same code that worked a few days back isn't working now. I'm wondering if Google has changed something in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for this. I'm not sure if it's the perfect solution, but I'm assuming the fix works because Google's still testing stuff out:

Go to `chrome://flags/` and enable `Experimental Web Platform features`. This enables audio recording via mediaDevices/MediaRecorder again.

I'm assuming that Google is A/B Testing this feature, so the default setting of disabled or enabled will vary from browser to browser and update to update.